# How can I get more intuition about CX?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and define $CX$ as the quotient space $X \times I / X \times \{0\}$. From my understanding $X \times \{0\}$ defines some sort of equivalence relation, but I am unsure how this can be described. Is this assumption correct? If so, what is a better description of the relation?

Comment: See William's answer for intuition. Formally, when $Z$ is a space and $A$ a subspace and we refer to the quotient space $Z/A$, the equivalence relation is $x \sim y$ if $x,y\in A$. Alternatively, you can let $Y$ be a one-point space and take $f:A\to Y$ be the attaching map; this induces the same equivalence relation and we obtain $Z/A = Z\cup_f Y$. We interpret $Z/A$ as starting with $Z$ and collapsing $A$ to a point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of this operation is the biggest source of intuition about it: it is called the "cone" over $X$.

Taking the quotient by $X \times \{0\}$ does in fact define an equivalence relation: it identifies all points in $x\times I$ with the second component (the one from $I$) equal to $0$.

Think about what happens when you apply $C$ to the circle: first you create $S^1 \times I$, a cylinder, and then you collapse one end of the cylinder (the one corresponding to $S^1\times \{0\}$) to a single point, forming a cone (topologically, a disk). In fact, this generalises to higher dimensions: $CS^n = D^n$, a fact whose proof could greatly help your intuition.

In general the operation $C$ is carried out (informally) by adjoining a single extra point to you space, and then forming lines between this point and every other point in the space.

Comment: One can imagine $X$ embedded in $R^n$ and the extra point being in $R^{n+1}$. This will work for most examples one cares about (finite dimensional CW complexes).